# How do I output the current db level on Mac?

Tags: macos, csv, processing, volume

Hello and thanks for checking out my question,

I am working on a project analysing film and visualizing the data I got from it. I'm quite new at programming and only have some basic experience in java and javascript. 
For my project I want to store the db levels of a movie in a csv file, to later work with the data in processing. I couldn't find anything that wasn't too complex for me to comprehend for Mac (OSX.)

Help would be much appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to break your problem down into smaller steps.

**Step 1:** Generating the CSV file.

There are probably a million different ways to do this, and that can be pretty confusing. But break this down into smaller sub-steps and then take those steps one at a time. Can you get a movie playing in Processing? There is a Video library that does just that. Then can you get the volume level every X seconds? You might start with a separate sketch that just prints something to the console every X seconds. For getting the volume, you might try out the Minim library. If that doesn't work, Google is your friend, and remember to keep breaking your problem down into smaller steps!

**Step 2:** Loading the CSV file.

Now that you have the CSV file, you have to load it into Proccessing. There are several functions in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) that might come in handy. Again, start with an example program that just prints the values to the console. Get that working perfectly before moving on.

**Step 3:** Visualizing the data.

Now that you have the data in your Processing code, you can start thinking about how you want to visualize the data. Maybe a line chart that just shows the volume over time just to start with.

If you get stuck on a specific step, then try to break it down into smaller sub-steps. Create an example program that just tests one of those smaller sub-steps (also known as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and you'll be able to ask a more specific code-oriented question. Good luck, sounds like an interesting project!